# GraphicsMagick и ImageMagick для nodejs под windows

Tags: windows, node.js, imagemagick

Столкнулся с необходимостью нарезать миниатюры файлов в своем проекте, так же их конвертировать между собой в разные форматы (jpeg, png и др.). Остановился на выборе imagemagick. Сделал все как [тут](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) описано. Установил GraphicsMagick-1.3.23-Q8-win64-dll.exe и ImageMagick-6.9.2-8-Q16-x64-dll.exe.

Тестовый пример:

```js
var fs = require('fs'), gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
        for(var i in files){
            gm(rootPath + files[i]).size(function(err, value){
                if(err){
                    console.error('[processingImages] %s',err);
                }
                console.log('[processingImages] %s -> size = %s',files[i],value);
            });
        }
```

```
Выдает ошибку Error: Command failed: identify.exe: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 80 www/img/Screenshots_2.jpg @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/322
```

После этого я нашел файл `identify.exe` и положил его в корень проекта, после этого получил ошибку `Error: Command failed`

Как правильно настроить использование модуля gm под windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написано, что "This is an abandoned version".
Лучше использовать [GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick for node](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm).

Ну а там в описании:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Потом:

```
npm install gm
```

Comment: извиняюсь за столь тупой вопрос, что за brew install? И где его взять для винды?

Comment: Установил GraphicsMagick-1.3.23-Q8-win64-dll.exe и ImageMagick-6.9.2-8-Q16-x64-dll.exe. В тестовом примере получаю ошибку: Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: identify "-ping" "-format" "%wx%h" "www/img/Screenshots_1.jpg" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found

Comment: После перезагрузки ПК получил Error: Command failed: identify.exe: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 80 `www/img/Screenshots_2.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/322. После этого я нашел  identify.exe и положил его в корень проекта, после этого получил ошибку Error: Command failed Тестовый скрипт выглядит так: https://jsfiddle.net/z3xtu372/

Comment: @sanu0074 brew  - модуль для компиляции. Ставить так `npm install -g brew`

Comment: Так что мне даст модуль brew? после его установки я не смогу выполнить команду brew install, т.к. это для MacOS. А в случае винды там написано скачать и установить либы, я это сделал (GraphicsMagick-1.3.23-Q8-win64-dll.exe и ImageMagick-6.9.2-8-Q16-x64-dll.exe). В комментах же описал что из этого вышло

Comment: @sanu0074 попробуйте не в корень проекта кинуть, а в PATH задать путь до него

Comment: не помогло, результат тот же